# Need to pull a list of image url's from a Mysql database based on a subdomain, and store them as a list

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a Mysql Forum database which I need to query all the posts in for a specific set of images, on a particular url.

The url's are of images hosted on a subdomain that we don't have access to like this "http://images.website.com/images/randomnumberhere.jpg".

I need a mysql query to pull these out and process them into a list which we can later loop through to grab them all and move them.(I got this part handled)

I'm a php/mysql programmer but this feels like a regex problem and i'm not so great with that yet.

The issue is we don't have a list of the images, and it's a big long random number (so far as I can see). So what I need is a string like "images.website.com/images/(randomnumbers).jpg" and then put them into a list.

Comment: What is the table set up like? Are the image URL's all in one field of a certain table, or multiple fields across multiple tables? Are they mixed in with other data, or is it just a list of the image URL's?

Comment: Hi Kacey, it's a single mediumtext field, in one table, with other text in (it's a forum so it could have any text in the field really).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to pull all of the text from the database, and then use PHP to create a list of the images, try something like this:

```
$image_list = array();

while($row = $sql->fetch_array())
{
    $text = $row['text'];
    /* Changed to preg_match_all */
    if(preg_match_all("/http:\/\/images.website.com\/images\/[0-9]+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)/i", $text, $matches))
    {
        $image_list[] = $matches[0];
    }
}
```

Nothing fancy, and I didn't test it, but it should work. That's a hardcoded regex that matches the URL you're looking for specifically. You may want to modify it so that it can match multiple domains from an array, or something, but it should get you started.

EDIT: Should have mentioned that you could then loop through the $image_list array to display the images, or whatever you're going to do with them.

Comment: This actually looks like what I'm looking for! I'll test this later and get back to you. Thanks Kacey

Comment: Hi Kacey, I tried your code (adapted a little) but it was only matching a single item if there was more than one image in the list. I just changed it to preg_match_all and it works. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You could get all fancy pants-like and use regular expressions,
but you could also try a simple

```
SELECT * FROM image_table WHERE image_source LIKE '%images.website.com/images/%'
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I think he does not have them in database, and wondering how to insert imagefilenames with knowing only the path, and no server access

Comment: I have the database, I can process this however necessary. This is close, and was my first guess. but I need to process them from just pulling out the entire medium text field, which will contain all the data in the forum post, into just a list of the images only. I can use php to do this but it's the matching within the text and pulling that single url out that I'm having the issue with.

Comment: Mmm.. what's the resultset of a query like this? P.S.: +1 for the answer

Comment: It would be a list of rows (i'd select specific columns) with the output being a bunch of text where each one contained that url, once or more in the string stored in that row.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rand = //rand() function or whatever you would like to create the random number, since you didn't give ranges, it might be an array aswell;
$string = "images.website.com/images/$rand.jpg";
```

Or even a simple loop:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++) {
echo $string = "images.website.com/images/$i.jpg";
}
```

It's up to you how would you use it with your database

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but, I'm not generating a list, I'm searching through text to find the links.